# Change mnemonic for "move to onedrive" in windows explorer context menu

Tags: windows-explorer, onedrive, context-menu

I don't want to remove "move to onedrive", just remove the mnemonic M which trolls the mnemonic for "rename".

Other context items mnemonics can be changed by editing where the ampersand is in the registry key setting up the context entry, but I couldn't find any key containing that text in a Registry search, and all tips regarding Onedrive in the context menu seem to contain only the program ID number.

(It is causing files to be accidentally moved to onedrive when I want to rename - extremely annoying to have to trawl and move the file back.)

Comment: See if you can find it using [ShellMenuView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html), then right-click and select Properties, where you can modify.

Comment: Thanks Harrymc for the useful tip.  It doesn't appear in a search for "onedrive", possibly because I blocked it (it's not appearing as "disabled"), will try unblocking and search again... to see if your comment is the answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the Registry key that adds `Move to OneDrive` to the context menu for file items:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\ FileSyncEx`
with a default value of:
`{CB3D0F55-BC2C-4C1A-85ED-23ED75B5106B}`

As menu text is hard-coded in the `.dll`, it can't be modified.

So, to achieve the behavior you want, disable the "built-in" `Move to OneDrive` by editing the `(Default)` data of the above key by pre-pending with any random character(s). I use:
`XXX {CB3D0F55-BC2C-4C1A-85ED-23ED75B5106B}`

[image]

and then recreate it via a custom context menu item with a different mnemonic. Save the following as a `.reg` file and merge.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\MoveToOneDrive]
@="Move to OneDrive"
"Icon"=hex(2):25,00,4c,00,6f,00,63,00,61,00,6c,00,41,00,70,00,70,00,44,00,61,\
  00,74,00,61,00,25,00,5c,00,4d,00,69,00,63,00,72,00,6f,00,73,00,6f,00,66,00,\
  74,00,5c,00,4f,00,6e,00,65,00,44,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,5c,00,4f,00,6e,\
  00,65,00,44,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,2c,00,30,00,\
  00,00

; Icon=%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe,0

; pure com objects
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\MoveToOneDrive\Command]
@="PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"gi -LiteralPath '%1' | sv 'File' ; ($comFolder = ($shell = New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace('shell:OneDrive')).MoveHere($file.FullName) ; $comFolder.Self.InvokeVerb() ; (@($shell.windows()).Where({$_.LocationName -eq $comFolder.Title}))[0].Document.SelectItem($comFolder.ParseName($File.Name),17)\""

; String construction
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\MoveToOneDrive\xxCommand]
@="PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"($comFolder = $shell.NameSpace('shell:OneDrive')).MoveHere('%1') ; Invoke-Expression ('explorer /select,{0}{1}{0}' -f [char]34 , ( Join-Path  $comFolder.Self.Path ( '%1'.Split('\\')[-1] )))\""

; First draft
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shell\MoveToOneDrive\xCommand]
@="PowerShell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -Command \"($comFolder = (New-Object -com shell.application).NameSpace('shell:OneDrive')).MoveHere('%1') ; $comFolder.Self.InvokeVerb()\""
```

You will get the blue flash of the **PowerShell** window, which bothers some, and can be eliminated by some trickery I never bother with. The blue flash lets you know it's working! :D

Not quite as smart as the built-in version, as this will appear for files already within the `OneDrive` hierarchy, but that's no biggie for a cognizant user.

Comment: Thanks, as I mentioned above I've already blocked it.  If someone can contribute how to create the custom menu item that would be an answer.

Comment: You mentioned that in the comments I see, but didn't say how...but anyway, see edit.